# SQLite in C: Getting multiple single valued stats from table more efficiently

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm interested in getting several single valued statistic from a table, log, that contains fields ID and LogTime.  I can do this with several SELECT * (SELECT  FROM log) statements linked together with UNION ALL like this:

```
sql_stmt = sqlite3_mprintf( \
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT MIN(LogTime) FROM log) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(LogTime) FROM log) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT LogTime FROM log WHERE LogTime > %f ORDER BY logTime LIMIT 1) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE LogTime > %f) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM log) UNION ALL \
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM log)", t1, t2);

sqlite3_exec(db, sql_stmt, f_CallBack, pCallBack_Data, &errmsg)
```

This puts the returned values into a structure defined as pCallBack_Data, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Maybe combining elements into a single SELECT like this?

```
SELECT MIN(LogTime), MAX(LogTime), COUNT(*) from log
```

I know that won't work because it returns three values in a single row where the other statements in the UNION return a single value.

Comment: you mean a single value per row ?

Comment: What's wrong with getting all the values back in a single row?

Comment: Yes, right now it returns a single value per row... but there's nothing wrong with getting everything back in one row.  I would just have to parse that row in the callback.  I'm not sure how to put everything in a single row with the "WHERE LogTime > %f" cases.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out after JeremyP suggested a single row option.  Everything will output in a single row by using a single SELECT * followed by the desired comma separated SELECTs. Unless someone can suggest a more efficient way I think I'll go with this:

```
sql_stmt = sqlite3_mprintf( \
"SELECT * FROM \
(SELECT MIN(LogTime), MAX(LogTime), COUNT(*), MIN(ID), MAX(ID) FROM log), \
(SELECT LogTime FROM log WHERE LogTime > %f ORDER BY logTime LIMIT 1), \
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE LogTime > %f)", t1, t2);
```

Comment: Hmmm... interesting.  I just did a test where I called these statements 1000 times.  The top statement with the UNION ALLs took 4.2 seconds to run while the more concise bottom statement took 9.6 seconds.  This is exactly why I'm looking for the more efficient way to do things.  Even though the bottom statement is more concise, it takes over 2x longer to execute.